# Same outputs come from query where different outputs expected

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using my downtime to learn SQL (Postgres) since I'm quite bad at it. I appreciate the patience and guidance.

I have two tables, table employee:

```
  fname   | minit |  lname  |    ssn    |   bdate    |         address         | sex |  salary  | super_ssn | dno 
----------+-------+---------+-----------+------------+-------------------------+-----+----------+-----------+-----
 James    | E     | Borg    | 888665555 | 1937-11-10 | 450 Stone, Houston TX   | M   | 55000.00 |           |   1
 John     | B     | Smith   | 123456789 | 1965-01-09 | 731 Fondren, Houston TX | M   | 30000.00 | 333445555 |   5
 Franklin | T     | Wong    | 333445555 | 1955-12-08 | 638 Voss, Houston TX    | M   | 40000.00 | 888665555 |   5
 Alicia   | J     | Zelaya  | 999887777 | 1968-01-19 | 3321 Castle, Spring TX  | F   | 25000.00 | 987654321 |   4
 Jennifer | S     | Wallace | 987654321 | 1941-06-20 | 291 Berry, Bellaire TX  | F   | 43000.00 | 888665555 |   4
 Ramesh   | K     | Narayan | 666884444 | 1962-09-15 | 975 Fire Oak, Humble TX | M   | 38000.00 | 333445555 |   5
 Joyce    | A     | English | 453453453 | 1972-07-31 | 5631 Rice, Houston TX   | F   | 25000.00 | 333445555 |   5
 Ahmad    | V     | Jabbar  | 987987987 | 1969-03-29 | 980 Dallas, Houston TX  | M   | 25000.00 | 987654321 |   4
```

And table department:

```
     dname      | dnumber |  mgr_ssn  | mgr_start  
----------------+---------+-----------+------------
 Research       |       5 | 333445555 | 1988-05-22
 Administration |       4 | 987654321 | 1995-01-01
 Headquarters   |       1 | 888665555 | 1981-06-19
```

I understood (mostly) of how joins work, but I'm stuck at self-joins.

What I want with this was to return a view that had employee name, supervisor name, and employee salary for each employee who works in the 'Research' department.

When I tried my hand at the self-joins, I'm doing something obviously wrong that I cannot pinpoint:

```
SELECT e.fname, e.lname, s.fname, s.lname, e.salary
FROM employee e JOIN employee s
ON e.ssn = s.super_ssn
JOIN department d 
ON d.dnumber = e.dno
WHERE d.dname = 'Research'
```

This returns three times the employee named `Franklin Wong` who is a manager. But if you see `employee.dno`, you will see that there are four people who work in the `Research` department, since the `dno` equivalent to 5 is the same `dnumber` in the department table.

What am I doing wrong here? Please and thank you.

Edit 1: I adjusted the `SELECT` statement and now I see the other employees. So **now the question is how do I get their salaries.**

Edit 2: The answer from Gordon, but with adjustments to get the manager's name instead of their `super_ssn`.

```
SELECT e.fname, e.lname, s.fname, s.lname, e.salary
FROM employee e JOIN
     employee s
     ON s.ssn = e.super_ssn JOIN
     department d 
     ON e.dno = d.dnumber
WHERE d.dname = 'Research'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your `JOIN` conditions have the tables reversed.  And, you want to join on the department number not on the SSN:

```
SELECT e.fname, e.lname, s.super_ssn, e.salary
FROM employee e JOIN
     employee s
     ON s.ssn = e.super_ssn JOIN
     department d 
     ON e.dno = d.dnumber
WHERE d.dname = 'Research'
```

Comment: Thanks once again, Gordon. I adjusted the `SELECT` statement to reflect the output and I get the correct output now. Will edit the question to reflect it.

Comment: What do you mean they are "reversed" though? I thought the order from left to right didn't matter? Or is it the other of the joins from table `employee` to table `company`? I will check the query and see if I can understand it myself. Thanks!

Comment: `s.ssn = e.super_ssn` rather than `s.uper_ssn = e.ssn`.  The *super*'s ssn needs to match the manager of the employee.

Comment: Gotcha. So the order actually does matter. Thanks!

Comment: @LukePerez . . . It is not the order, *per se*.  It is what columns come from which tables.

Comment: Aren't the tables the same in this case? Are `employee e` and `employee s` considered different tables by the query even though they are data in the same table?